# Stand-alone Server Object Extension (SOE)

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, server-object-extension

I would like to setup a REST service through ArcGIS Server.

In this case I do not need a map service, but it seems like you can only deploy an SOE as an extension to another service.  It seems weird to attach the SOE to a map service that it is not related to.

I would prefer to create the service as an SOE since it uses ArcObjects and so that it can be managed and deployed through the AGS management console.

I'm working with ArcGIS Server 10.1 on Windows with IIS.

Comment: If it is not made to run with a Map Service, have you thought of creating it as a GeoProcessing service.

Comment: Which version you are using 10 or 10.1 ?

Comment: ArcGIS Server 10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried it, but you should be able to create a REST service using the [WCF REST template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd), then use the [StaTaskScheduler](https://web.archive.org/web/20160724072136/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx) as described in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/53165/59).

However, you would not be able to manage the service using ArcGIS Server Manager.  Instead, you would need to use IIS.

Also, as Khattab suggests, you could implement a [custom IGpTool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000mrs000000) and deploy as a GP service.  In a multi-machine site deployment of GP services based on custom gp tools is a bit more painful - you need to manually call the 64 bit version EsriRegasm on each machine in the site where the gp service will be run.

Comment: Thanks Kirk.  It sounds like this is not something AGS is intended to support.

Comment: @Preston Sometimes things that AGS does not intend to support works better than things that it is explicitly supposed to support.  I'm currently dealing with some very strange behavior of a custom .NET gp tool published as a service.  The tool runs fine when invoked from arcmap as a background gp process (running as the gis soc service account).  However I'm seeing different results (though no error) when run as a gp service.  If I don't get this resolved maybe I'll try the StaTaskScheduler.